# Re enter US under VWP after a short stay (17 days) only 16 days after exit

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Can I re enter the US under the VWP after a short stay of 17 days, only 16 days after exit?

EDIT: Those 17 days are the only time I have been in the US for at least the last year.

Comment: Probably, but it depends. How many days have you been in the US, total, in the past six months?

Comment: Just those 17 days

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The ESTA can be used multiple times (until it expires), and the VWP allows you to stay for up to 90 days per visit. There are rules about whether or not the 90 day clock stops or not depending where you go outside the US, but for an absence of just 16 days it doesn't matter for you. From the point of view of the VWP admission days, it would be as if you had stayed in the US for the whole 33 days (which means you have 57 days left).

Comment: Okay thanks! So the border guard will not be thinking I'm trying to game the system or something. If I only sty, like I intend to, for around 10 days then I should be all good?

Comment: Yes, that will be no problem. If you did something else, like stayed for 80 days, left for two weeks, then came back and intended to stay for another 80 days, that would be trying to game the system and they probably wouldn't let you back in.

Comment: Okay awesome. So the stamp I got last time is essentially still valid?

Comment: You will get a new stamp in your passport. It's your ESTA that is still valid, which allows you to apply for VWP entry.

Comment: The ESTA is the "thing that let's you get a stamp" and the stamp is "the stamp"  :)  This is such a common question on here!  :)